# Can we use "would" to talk about the future?

Tags: modal-verbs

For example:

> I would join your party tomorrow, but I am busy in something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

This is how English forms conditional clauses.  The condition is implied "If I was not busy".

To talk about a past conditional (that is one which is counter-factual) you need "would have"

> I would have gone to your party, but I was busy yesterday.